# Add ampersand to sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of Advertisers and am trying to match data from user query string.  We have advertisers, such as D&G and I am wondering how to write sql so that it is a valid search?  I am using LIKE but can't seem to make anything work or find a decent answer via google, so how do I do it?  I tried double quotes and lines like below:

```
AND (UPPER(als.SearchString) LIKE UPPER('"D&G%"'))
```

Thanks

Ok, so my post is being put into question!  Here is my total WHERE clause:

```
WHERE     (a.CountryCodes & 3 > 0) AND (na.PubDate BETWEEN '4/22/2001' AND '4/22/2013') AND (UPPER(als.SearchString) LIKE UPPER('D%') ESCAPE '\')
```

Obviously the '&' has been removed and this returns 419 results including such entities as 'D&G Communications Group.'  However, as soon as I try and implement 'D\&' within the LIKE clause I get no records returned.  I am very willing to accept that I am missing something and would be more than happy for that to be pointed out :)

Comment: Why the double quotes? This seems to work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81cd1/2 so I guess there is something you are not telling us. And what exactly does "*can't seem to make anything work*" mean? What is the error message? What is the result you get? What is the data in the table?

Comment: Not quite sure why you voted it down?  I am not getting an error message but I am not getting any results.  I was trying the double quotes in order to see if it work, similar to some suggestion on other forums.  'D&G' is in the table, matches on 'D%' or similar query strings but I can't seem to make anything work if I put the ampersand in the string.

Comment: I did not downvote. Did you check the SQLFiddle link? It clearly shows that the `like` does work with an `&` and does not need any escaping. You **are** using SQL Server, right?

Comment: I am  - I find sql fiddle to be very unreliable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
set ESCAPE \
AND (UPPER(als.SearchString) LIKE UPPER('"D\&B%"'))
```

Comment: Why would you need that? `&` is not a wildcard character for a LIKE expression. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81cd1/2

Answer (score 0):

you can concatenate it with || or set define off

source: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=466604

Answer (score 0):

Add `ESCAPE` to the end of the `LIKE` condition and use that character in the condition.

```
AND (UPPER(als.SearchString) LIKE UPPER('"D\&G%"')) ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: I tried this: AND (als.SearchString LIKE 'D\&G%' ESCAPE '\')
but I still get nothing.

Comment: There is no need to escape a `&`. You only need that for wildcard characters (`%` and `_`)

Comment: The & is not an operator this is D&G Advertising, it's a company name.  You don't need to escape % in a query it just stands for anything after!