# cannot insert a string with & into the database from asp.net code

Tags: asp.net, database, string, c#-4.0

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT_ACS_STUDIES_DATA";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mrn", mrn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@log_id", crid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@panel_id", panel_id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROC_NAME", procName);
```

It fails when the vairable @PROC_NAME has a value with & in it  - e.g. A & A
What is the correct syntax to insert strings which have these characters?

Comment: Encode the string before sending it.

Comment: This is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178539/add-ampersand-to-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

It sails because when using C# parameters you need to encode all special characters. C# will reject unencoded special characters to help prevent SQL Inject Attacks. You can use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(string)` to encode it.